# Salesforce SOAP SessionId as REST token

Tags: rest, soap, salesforce

I'm logging my users in using SOAP in my app. But then I want to use Analytics API, which is REST. But I don't want them to enter their credentials all over again. 
Is there a way that I can use my already obtained SOAP sessionId as the token for REST API?
When I tried to do that, I got an authentication error back from the REST call. Did I miss something or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes its possible, just use the SOAP session Id in the same place you'd use a access token you'd gotten via OAuth, by adding a `Authorization: Bearer {sessionId}` HTTP header to your REST API requests.